# bootstrap install .net on server 2003/2008

Tags: .net, wix, windows-server, bootstrapper

I have read [this](http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2010/05/19/creating-a-bootstrapper-with-dotnetinstaller/) article on creating a bootstrapper to install the .NET framework.

I have a wix setup project and need to do a similar thing and more.

Is there an alternative way to install .NET on server 2008 (in an automatic/automated fashion) as the article claims that it needs to be added as a server role and cannot just be installed.

Does anyone know also if its a similar issue on Windows 2003?

Comment: this possibly belongs on serverfault but it does have some overlap with SO

Comment: Am I right that this only applies to Windows Server 2008 R2, because Server 2008 does not include .net 3.5 by default. Related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/33521/install-net-3-5-sp1-on-windows-7-rc

Comment: I just did a test, on windows server 2008 I could install .net with a ClickOnce bootstrapper, on windows server 2003 and 2003 R2 I have never had problems too.

Comment: no, that was not R2, I have no R2 close where I can test this.